# How to detect if font is applicable on text layer or not before applying the font?

Tags: apache-flex

I created a panel in flex which will have 2 combo-boxes that will display system font family and font styles and when user selects any font family or style from the combo-box the font gets applied on the selected text layer. But when I try to apply few fonts for eg Euro sign then the text in the selected text layers become all rectangles. I found that Character panel of Photoshop does not apply the font(Euro sign) on the selected text layer.

Is there any method in flex which can help us detect whether a font is applicable on the selected text layer or not?

Thanks

Comment: Can refer link: - http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/03/31/determining-if-a-specific-font-is-embedded-in-a-flex-application/

Comment: Hi, I tried the method "isFontFaceEmbedded". But this method is for embedded fonts and not system fonts.I need a method which can tell me either a system font can be applied or not?

Answer (score 0):

For your Q. I need a method which can tell me either a system font can be applied or not?
Here I have sample where you can read System Font and check on combobox if that font is available in system font or not. Please find below code: -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

            private var systemFontsCollection:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(); 

            private function getSystemFont():void
            {
                var fonts:Array = Font.enumerateFonts(true).sortOn("fontName");
                for (var i:int = 0; i < fonts.length; i++) {
                    systemFontsCollection.addItem(new String(fonts[i].fontName));
                }
            }


            private function init():void 
            {
                var fontName:String = fontName.selectedLabel;

                if(systemFontsCollection.contains(fontName))
                {
                    trace(" ----System Font is applied ----");
                }
                else{
                    trace(" ----System Font is NOT applied ----");
                }

            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <mx:Form>
        <mx:FormItem label="Font name:">
            <mx:ComboBox id="fontName" change="init();" creationComplete="getSystemFont()">
                <mx:dataProvider>
                    <fx:Array>
                        <fx:String>Arial</fx:String>
                        <fx:String>ArialEmbedded</fx:String>
                        <fx:String>Verdana</fx:String>
                        <fx:String>VerdanaEmbedded</fx:String>
                    </fx:Array>
                </mx:dataProvider>
            </mx:ComboBox>
        </mx:FormItem>
    </mx:Form>
</s:Application>
```